# Give an example in $\Bbb R^2$ to show that the union of two subspaces is not, in general, a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve this on my own.

Give an example in $\Bbb R^2$ to show that the union of two subspaces is not, in general, a subspace.

I feel the need to use functions to illustrate this, but it would not be in $\Bbb R^2$.

Any hints?

My answer,

> Let $u= \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{array} \right] $ and $v= \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{array} \right] $, then let L={Span{$u$}, Span{$v$}} or {$(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2 | x=0 \text{ or } y=0$}  $u+v= \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 \\ 0 \\ \end{array} \right] + \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 \\ 1 \\ \end{array} \right] = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 \\ 1 \\ \end{array} \right] \\ (u+v)\notin L \text{, thus L is not closed under addition for subspaces.}$

Comment: You should be able to pick **any** two non-0 proper subspaces of $\Bbb R^2,$ and find that their union is not a subspace.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the $y$-axis and the $x$-axis. Think about taking the vector $(1,0)+(0,1)$.

Comment: I thought of using $u=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$
and $v=
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 \\
1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$, then the union of the Span{$u$} and Span{$v$}. But I still don't see it.

Comment: Is the vector $(1,1)$ in this union?

Comment: @user1766555: That's a great idea. Did you check which properties of a subspace that union satisfies?

Comment: I just didn't know how to show the union properly. I see what you mean now. Should I say, Let $L=${Span{$u$},Span{$v$}}, to introduce my union?

Comment: The union is $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|x=0 \ \text{or } \ y=0\}$ (Right?). What are the two biggest conditions for a subset of a vector Space to be a subspace? Have you checked those?

Comment: I see that defining the union that way would satisfy it, but is my way of saying it incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

It is more general than that: in a group, the union of two subgroups is a subgroup if and only if one of them is contained in the other.

To see this, suppose none of the subgroups $H, K\subset G$ is contained in the other. Pick an element $h\in H\smallsetminus K$ and an element $k\in K\smallsetminus H$. If $H\cup K$ is a subgroup, $hk\in H\cup K$. Is it in $H$ or is it in $K$?

Comment: what does the ∖ signify?

Comment: $H\smallsetminus K$ is the difference for sets, i.e. the  set of elements in $H$, but not in $K$.